# nmap нестабильное обнаружение ip

Tags: сеть, сканирование-портов

Сканирую сеть на наличие службы на определенном порту

`nmap -n -T4 -p 7777 -sS --open X.X.X.0-255`

Результат сканирования отображается рандомно, т.е. запускаю сканирование несколько раз и список ip адресов может появиться сразу, либо после N-ого сканирования.
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Если изменить шаблон настроек управления временем с -T4 -T2 тогда находит всегда, но время возрастает с нескольких секунд до 12 минут